# pandas - how to make same row blank then write to excel with merged cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, merge

This question is actually about 2 cases:

1. make the same value in column of pandas dataframe to be blank
2. save the result dataframe to excel with merged cell and the text is  on vertical center

**1. the dataframe part**

for the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['Huawei','Huawei','Huawei', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Samsung', 'Samsung'],
                    'Year': [2011, 2011, 2018, 2011, 2019, 2018, 2019],
                    'Product': ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'A1', 'A2', 'S1', 'S2']})
df = df.sort_values(by=['Company', 'Year'])
df
```

i.e.

```
   Company    Year  Product
3   Apple       2011   A1
4   Apple       2019   A2
0   Huawei      2011   H1
1   Huawei      2011   H2
2   Huawei      2018   H3
5   Samsung     2018   S1
6   Samsung     2019   S2
```

what I need is `mergeCell(df, on = ['Company'])` returns

```
   Company    Year  Product
3   Apple       2011   A1
4               2019   A2
0   Huawei      2011   H1
1               2011   H2
2               2018   H3
5   Samsung     2018   S1
6               2019   S2
```

while `mergeCell(df, on = ['Company', 'Year'])` returns

```
   Company    Year  Product
3   Apple       2011   A1
4   Apple       2019   A2
0   Huawei      2011   H1
1                      H2
2   Huawei      2018   H3
5   Samsung     2018   S1
6   Samsung     2019   S2
```

I wrote one, but obviously it is not terse and has bug

```
def mergeCell(df, on):
    import copy

    dfMerged = df[on]

    dfTmp = np.empty((df.shape[0], len(on)), dtype=object)
    lastRow = ()
    idx = 0
    for row in dfMerged.itertuples():
        if idx == 0:
            lastRow = row[1:]
            dfTmp[idx, :] = lastRow
        else:
            if row[1:] != lastRow:
                lastRow = row[1:]
                dfTmp[idx, :] = lastRow
            else:
                dfTmp[idx, :] = np.empty((1, len(on)), dtype=object)

        idx += 1 

    dfTmp = pd.DataFrame(dfTmp)
    dfTmp.columns = on


    dfCopied = copy.deepcopy(df)
    for idxRow in range(df.shape[0]):
        for idxCol in on:
            dfCopied.loc[idxRow, idxCol] = dfTmp.loc[idxRow, idxCol]

    return dfCopied
```

so, is there a built-in way to do so?

**2. save the result dataframe to excel with merged cell and the text is on vertical center**
for this part, I have no idea except for doing what I have do in the above `mergeCell` function

thanks

Comment: I suggest you ask the second question *separately*, showing what you've researched. I've addressed the first question only in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a built-in way to do so?

Yes, you can use use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). But be careful, an "empty cell" in Pandas may mean one of two things: either `NaN` or the empty string `''`. Since you are concerned about presentation, I assume you want the latter.

**Example 1: `pd.Series.duplicated`**

```
col = 'Company'
df[col] = df[col].mask(df[col].duplicated(), '')

print(df)

#    Company  Year Product
# 3    Apple  2011      A1
# 4           2019      A2
# 0   Huawei  2011      H1
# 1           2011      H2
# 2           2018      H3
# 5  Samsung  2018      S1
# 6           2019      S2
```

**Example 2:** `pd.DataFrame.duplicated`

```
cols = ['Company', 'Year']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].duplicated(), '')

print(df)

#    Company  Year Product
# 3    Apple  2011      A1
# 4    Apple  2019      A2
# 0   Huawei  2011      H1
# 1                     H2
# 2   Huawei  2018      H3
# 5  Samsung  2018      S1
# 6  Samsung  2019      S2
```